# I still have Tags listed in my profile though I have no more questions or answers

Tags: bug, status-norepro, user-accounts

I (still) have an account on Christianity.

After the moderators and myself updated, blocked and removed my questions, finally I remained without questions.

However I observed that the tags are not properly cleaned, as you can observe in the picture:

[image]

Comment: How long ago were the posts removed?  The tags list has some lag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the page, I see no tags there.

As usual - http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: I see no tags anymore... maybe you are right... However is strange that other things where removed (from cach?) but not tags....

Comment: Different items have different cache durations - and some are  not cached at all.